# SQL Server + excel

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

estoy trabajando en hacer un update de registros a una tabla de SQL Server sin embargo los datos para hacer el procedimiento estan en una hoja de Excel, la duda en especifico es como puedo mandar a llamar los datos de la hoja de Excen en mi consulta de sql el Excel es 2016 y la base de datos es SQL Server 2014

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado hasta ahorita, pon parte de tu código y podremos orientarte.

Comment: Intenta crear un `Stored Procedure` y el **Excel** conviertelo a `XML` y lo mandas como paramétro(Como un string), para recorrer el XML debes usar cursores. [Consulta este enlace](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-handle-input-and-output-XML-in-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure)

Comment: claro, tengo mi consulta de actualizacion ya diseñada que es esta update dbo.Documents set Name = "aqui quiero jalar datos de Excel", Description = "aqui quiero jalar datos de Excel" where ID1 = "aqui quiero jalar datos de Excel"